# ffmpeg fail, job commandline

Tags: python, macos, ffmpeg

I am trying to run DeepFaceLab, but FFmpeg returned an error:

```
[0] Enter FPS ( ?:help ) : 0
0
[png] Output image format ( png/jpg ?:help ) : png
png
/!\ ffmpeg fail, job commandline:['ffmpeg', '-i', '/Users/user/Documents/deepfake/DeepFaceLab_MacOS/workspace/data_src.mp4', '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24', '/Users/user/Documents/deepfake/DeepFaceLab_MacOS/workspace/data_src/%5d.png']
Done
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you please include an error code or the full command output? There is not enough information right now.

Comment: there is no error code
Ok, I use an interface from GitHub for DFL so that's all I have:

Comment: I understand it doesn't show you the error code in this log, but this is just calling out to a command line script. You should be able to run `ffmpeg -i /Users/user_name/Documents/deepfake/DeepFaceLab_MacOS/workspace/data_src.mp4 -pix_fmt rgb24 '/Users/user_name/Documents/deepfake/DeepFaceLab_MacOS/workspace/data_src/%5d.png'` on the command line and get a much more verbose output.

Comment: so I reinstalled ffmpeg and it worked tnx)